# How to return to parent function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have the following function at the moment, and I want to return `"aaa"` to the parent function (getStream), this is the code I have atm:

```js
module.exports.getStream = (figure) => {
    plotly.plot(figure, imgOpts, function(err, stream) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return "error";
        }

        return "aaa";
    });
};
```

Right now, however, it returns `undefined`. What's the best solution to solve that problem?

Comment: What do you "it returns `undefined`"? What is "it"? Do you want the `plotly.plot` call to return `"aaa"` or do you want `getStream` to return it?

Comment: By the use of a callback in `plotly.plot`, I'm assuming it's an asynchronous function? If so, you need to wait for it to resolve. Look into `Promises` and `async/await`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getStream` does not return anything (therefore its return value is `undefined`). You have to add return before `plotly` or just remove curly braces. Also you'll have to return a promise, because that third argument of `plotly.plot` method is a callback function (I guess).

```
module.exports.getStream = (figure) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    plotly.plot(figure, imgOpts, function(err, stream) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject("error");
        }

        resolve("aaa");
    });
  })
```

and then somewhere in the app:

```
const foo = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await getStream(figure)
    console.log(result) // 'aaa'
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)  // 'error'
  }
}
```

Comment: ```js
module.exports.getStream = (figure) =>
    plotly.plot(figure, imgOpts, function(err, stream) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return "error";
        }

        return "aaa";
    });
```
still returns `undefined` and not `"aaa"` / error.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realise that `plotly.plot` method doesn't return anything. So you'll have to use a promise I guess, I'll update my answer